# Validating Java MessageFormat strings

Tags: java, validation, playframework, messageformat

I'm working on a Play 2 app which is being translated. Play uses Java's `MessageFormat` behind the scenes so I have a fair number of property values, ala:

`my.interface.key={0,choice,0#{0} families|1#1 family|1<{0,number,integer} families}`

I just received back a translation of this in the form:

`my.interface.key={0,choix,0#{0} familles|1#1 famille|1<{0,nombre,entier}  familles}`

If it's not obvious, some bits of that should not have been translated, but mistakes will happen from time to time. That's fair enough, but I'm sure there must be a way of validating these strings prior to my app crashing at runtime with a `IllegalArgumentException: unknown format type at ...` exception. Preferably with a Git commit hook, or even an SBT build task.

If I was to hack this up myself I would probably make a tool to read these property files and check that, for each value, running `MessageFormat.format(value)` doesn't blow up.

Ideally I could do this via a Perl (or Python) script. Sadly, the only non-Java library I can find - [Text::MessageFormat](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Text-MessageFormat-0.01/lib/Text/MessageFormat.pm) on CPAN - doesn't seem to support the most error-prone formats, such as pluralisation.

Can anyone suggest a more sensible approach based on existing tooling before I dive in?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @miindlek The nearest I came was as [this function in the `build.sbt`](https://github.com/EHRI/ehri-frontend/blob/master/build.sbt#L176), which is runs on the [compile phase](https://github.com/EHRI/ehri-frontend/blob/master/build.sbt#L247). This spits out an error if there's something iffy in the messages value format.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. Our solution was to create classes that model the structure of the message format, then use XML to define the messages in our message bundle.

If the translator uses an XML editor then there is some hope they won't "break" the structure of the message.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62612591/263801) for details.